# Website won't play background video in google chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, google-chrome

I have a website: www.OnCampusChef.com

it is supposed to play a short video clip in the background using a jQuery Youtube Player plugin, and it does work on most people's computers. In fact, it even works on safari on my macbook pro. However, for some reason I can't get it to play on my google chrome. I have tried restarting my computer, uninstalling chrome, clearing the cache and browser history, making sure the javascript in my browser has been enabled, but to no avail.

Any insights as to what could be causing the problem?

The weird part is that it works just fine on my other browsers and even on my localhost.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Works just fine in my Chrome ?

Comment: exactly! that's the confusing part, it won't work on my chrome only!

Comment: Do you have some extension installed that might be blocking it?

Comment: i tried disabling extensions and running in incognito and also pressing CTRL F5 but nothing seems to fix it. This is a very strange problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar issue recently with a web-site i'm building (lisa-lab.com). What I've discovered is that the problem occurs only on Google Chrome for Mac, and only for videos shorter than 10 seconds. I've been able to narrow it down to the Accept-Ranges: bytes header, but I'm still uncertain as to why that fails for short videos, but works fine on larger ones. I think I may have to tweak my Apache settings a little.

Anyway, hopefully this helps you troubleshoot your issue.